# Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a locally ringed space, does there exists a monomorphism $\iota:U\rightarrow X$ for all open $U$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X$ be a locally ringed space, and suppose that $U\subset X$ is an open set equipped with the sheaf of rings $\mathcal{O}_X|_U$ defined by $\mathcal{O}_X|_U(V)=\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ for all $V\subset U$. I am trying to show that this ringed space comes equipped with a natural monomorphism $\iota:U\rightarrow X$.

It is clear that $(U,\mathcal O_X|_U)$ is a locally ringed space, and moreover that the
inclusion map $\iota:U\rightarrow X$ is an injection and thus a monomorphism
in the category of topological spaces. We thus need to describe a map $\iota^\sharp:
  \mathcal O_X\rightarrow \iota_*(\mathcal O_X|_U)$. Let $V\subset X$ be open, and note that:
$$\begin{align*}
    \iota^{-1}(V)=V\cap U
  \end{align*}$$
as if $x\in V\cap U$, then we have $x\in U$ and $x\in V$, hence $\iota(x)=x\in V$, so
$x\in \iota^{-1}(V)$. If $x\in \iota^{-1}(V)$, then we have that $x\in U$, and $\iota(x)= x\in V$,
so $x\in V$ and $U$.
We thus define $\iota^\sharp$
on open sets as:
$$\begin{align*}
    \iota^\sharp_V:\mathcal O_X(V)&\longrightarrow (\iota_*\mathcal O_X|_U)(V)=\mathcal O_X|_U(\iota^{-1}(V))=\mathcal O_X(U\cap V)\\
                       s&\longmapsto s|_{U\cap V}
  \end{align*}$$
We note that this commutes with restriction maps, as if $W\subset V$ then:
\begin{align*}
    \iota^\sharp_W(\theta^V_W(s))=\theta^W_{W\cap U}\circ \theta^V_W(s)=\theta^V_{W\cap U}(s)
  \end{align*}
while:
\begin{align*}
    \theta^V_W\circ \iota^\sharp_V(s)=\theta^{V\cap U}_{W\cap U}\circ \theta^V_{V\cap U}(s)=
    \theta^V_{W\cap U}(s)
  \end{align*}
so this is a morphism of sheaves. We check that $\iota^\sharp_x$ is a surjection for all $x$.
Let $s_x\in  (\iota_*(\mathcal O_X|_U))$, then for some $V\subset X$, and some $s\in \mathcal O_X(U\cap V)$,
we have that $s_x=[V,s]$. However, we have that $[U\cap V,s]\in (\mathcal O_X)_x$, so trivially:
\begin{align*}
    \iota^\sharp_x([U\cap V,s])=[U\cap V, s]
  \end{align*}
We want to show that $[V,s]=[U\cap V, s]$. Let $W=U\cap V$, then we have that:
\begin{align*}
    \theta^V_{U\cap V}(s)=\theta^{U\cap V}_{U\cap V}(s)=s
  \end{align*}
so $\iota^\sharp_x$ is a surjection, and thus an epimorphism for all $x$. It follows that $\iota^\sharp$ is an epimorphism.

Since $\iota:U\rightarrow X$ is a monomorphism, and $\iota^\sharp$ is an epimorphism, does it follow that $\iota$ (I guess really the pair $(\iota,\iota^\sharp)$) is then a monomorphism? If not, then what is the issue?

Also, it seems $(\iota,\iota^\sharp)$ is an isomorphism onto itself, as restricting the image of $\iota$ we get a homeomorphism $\iota:U\rightarrow U\subset X$, and then $\iota^\sharp:\mathcal{O}_X|_U\rightarrow \iota_*(\mathcal O_X|_U)$ as defined is just the identity map on all open subsets of $U$, is this true?

Comment: @KReiser The Latex wasn't compiling so I posted the question to see what was wrong. It is fixed now.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am not sure what you mean by your first comment, For your second, I mean if we view $\iota$ as a map $U\rightarrow U$, and $\iota^\sharp$ as morphism $\mathcal{O}_X|_U\rightarrow (\iota_*\mathcal{O}_X|_U)$ then the $\iota$ is a homeomorphism, and $\iota^\sharp$ is an isomorphism. I am essentially saying that $(\iota,\iota^\sharp):(U,\mathcal{O}_X|_U)\rightarrow (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is an open embedding.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Oh I see what you mean now. Will edit to fix.